# Create small gap in horizontal line between two columns

Tags: tables

I need a simple 3x3 table. I know that using two `\hline` in a row, will create a nice bit of spacing between the two rows. I would like to create the same effect except vertically. Here is my table:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l||l|l|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
    \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    \hline
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

I would like cells 1,4 and 7 to be separated from 2,5 and 8 in the same way that 1,2 and 3 are from 4,5 and 6.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See `hhline` package ... and please consider @Rmano comment!

Comment: @Rmano My bad, will do so in the future

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, that worked.

Comment: Andy, if you do now, I can provide an answer. So far I'm  not willing write MWE (Minimal Working Example) from scratch ...